# Access Request Data sent, inside requestFailed Function ASIHttpRequest

Tags: objective-c, asihttprequest

How to access the (POST)data sent with the request from the requestFailed/requestFinished function.

```
-  (void) abc {  
    NSString *postString = @"john";  
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://abc.com"];  
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];  
    [request setPostValue:postString forKey:@"name"];  
    [request setDelegate:self];  
    [request startAsynchronus];  
}  
- (void) requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request  
{   
    // Question is whether the request holds the sent post values.  
    // If it holds. how can we access them.  
    // i tried using [request valueForKey:@"name"];  
    // but it won't work.  
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Handling success and failure for multiple requests in delegate methods
>
> If you need to handle success and failure on many different types of
>   request, you have several options:
>
> If your requests are all of the same broad type, but you want to
>   distinguish between them, you can set the userInfo NSDictionary
>   property of each request with your own custom data that you can read
>   in your finished / failed delegate methods. For simpler cases, you can
>   set the request’s tag property instead. Both of these properties are
>   for your own use, and are not sent to the server.
>
> If you need to handle success and failure in a completely different way for each
>   request, set a different setDidFinishSelector / setDidFailSelector for
>   each request For more complex situations, or where you want to parse
>   the response in the background, create a minimal subclass of
>   ASIHTTPRequest for each type of request, and override requestFinished:
>   and failWithError:.

That provided me a good solution to handle different requests.

Comment: yeah got that from ASIHTTPREQUEST docs.. anyways thanks for the info.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this -

```
- (void)requestFinished:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request {
   NSLog(@"Response %d ==> %@", request.responseStatusCode, [request responseString]);
}
```

You can also handle other methods if you choose, such as:

```
- (void)requestStarted:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request;
- (void)requestFailed:(ASIHTTPRequest *)request;
```

The docs are located at http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/ and are fantastic.

Comment: yeah. i can access the responseString.. the problem is i couldn't makeout for which request i am handling the response.. the request parameters differentiates b/w the requests.. i need to access the request parameters(dat are sent with the request)..

Answer (score 0):

You can cast your request into a ASIFormDataRequest:

```
if ([request isKindOfClass:[ASIFormDataRequest class]]) {
   ASIFormDataRequest *requestWithPostDatas = (ASIFormDataRequest *)request;
   NSArray *myPostData = [requestWithPostDatas getPostData];
}
```

You will also have to make "postData" accessible with a "getPostData" public function in ASIFormDataRequest.